# DB data provider not found after change used .NET Framework version

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have WPF project in VS2012 in which use Linter data provider. I would like to use .NET Framework 4.0 instead 4.5 (by default), but after change framework version I get an error, that my DB data provider not found.

I create new WPF project and insert next code into MainWindow ctor;

```
    var _linterFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.LinterClient");
```

Run - its ok.
After change the .NET framework version from 4.5 to 4.0 (in project properties) there is exception (Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.)
I try to change back .NET framework version, but still have the error.

Needed assembly correctly installed in GAC; machine.config also contains neccessary data:

```
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
        <!-- ... -->
          <add name="Linter Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.LinterClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Linter" type="System.Data.LinterClient.LinterClientFactory, System.Data.LinterClient, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=38a8bb1edf13da9d" /> 
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try wrapping in a try{} catch(OleDbException e){} to see if you can get a more specific error message?

Comment: @Killingsworth, In my case ArgumentException is thrown without any details and inner exceptions. Moreover, I did not find my provider in DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses()